# Implementing forgotten password in Firebase Auth and ReactJS

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to implement a "forgotten password" feature on my login page, however, it doesn't seem to be working. I am getting the following error in console:

```
FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.
```

So I believe it might be a firebase rules issue?

Code:

```
export default class ForgottenPassword extends Component {

    state = {
        email: ""
    }


    handleChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({
          [e.target.id]: e.target.value
        })
      }


    handleForgottenPassword = () => {
       firebase.auth().sendPasswordResetEmail(this.state.email).then(function() {
            alert('Please check your email')
        }).catch(function (e){
            console.log(e)
        }) 

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className = "ForgottenPasswordContainer">
                <form className="ForgottenPassword">
                    <h5> Forgotten your password? </h5> 
                    <p> No worries, just enter your email below and we will send you a link to reset it!</p>
                    <label htmlFor = "email"> Email </label><br/>
                    <input type="text" className="EmailAddress" placeholder = "Enter your email address" name = "email" id = "email" onChange = {this.handleChange}/> <br/>
                    <button className = "Button" onClick = {() => this.handleForgottenPassword()}> Submit </button>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Firestore rules:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write, delete, update: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your security rules don't allow any access unless the user is authenticated, and I'm assuming that a user wanting to request a password reset email isn't authenticated, so that may be the answer to your question.

Comment: @BrianBurton Thanks for this, I am incredibly new to Firestore rules, what would be the best way to get around this? I want the database to be secure but I still need the forgotten password to be implemented (I'm a designer so I'm sorry if this seems stupid)

Comment: The error doesn't appear related to the code that you posted.  What I think is happening is that you've subscribed to a Firestore collection/document somewhere in your code and since you're not authenticated and you're not handling the error, it's being displayed in the console.  The reason that the reset email isn't being sent could be as simple as the `email` variable being empty, set to the email of a non-existent user or you've just sent too many to a single user.

Comment: @BrianBurton I've set it so all non-authenticated users can read the database and now the error has gone but yeah as you said, it seems like it wasn't anything to do with that since it still doesn't seem to be working >.< I'll keep playing with it! Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Beware that `request.auth != null` is *not* considered secure.  Firebase Auth allows anyone to create an account without ever visiting your website.  Your database configuration would allow me to create an account and then delete your entire database.